# $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ independent with standard Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, independence

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables, each with standard Gaussian distribution. For a given $K>0$, prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\log{P\left(\left |\frac{X_1+\,...\,+X_n}{n}\right| \geq K\right)}=-\frac{K^2}{2} $$

I don't know how I can deal with this logarithm. I tried to rewrite the equation as:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(P\left(\left |\frac{X_1+\,...\,+X_n}{n}\right| \geq K\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{-\frac{K^2}{2}}$$

so that now I could get rid of the logarithm and get a nice looking $e^{-\frac{K^2}{2}}$. But I actually don't know what to do with that. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$ random variables it follows that 
$$\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n} \sim N\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Can you show where you are stuck in your computation?

Comment: Let $Y_n=\frac{X_1+\,...\,+X_n}{n}$. Since $Y_n \,~\,N(0, 1/n)$, we get  $$P(|Y_n|\geq k)=1-P(|Y_n|<k)=1-P(-k<Y_n<-k)=1-\int_{-k}^{k}\frac{\sqrt{n}e^{\frac{-nx^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$$ That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: correction: the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in the integral is supposed to be in the denominator

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{P}(-k < Y_n <k) = \mathbb{P}(Y_n < k) - \mathbb{P}(Y_n < -k) = \mathbb{P}(Y_n < k) - [1-\mathbb{P}(Y_n < k)] = 2 \mathbb{P}(Y_n < k) -1$.

Comment: Ok, so that means $P(|Y_n|\geq K)=2(1-P(Y_n< K))$ and therefore: 

$$\frac{1}{n}\log{P(|Y_n|\geq K)}=\frac{1}{n}\log(2(1-P(Y_n< K)))=\frac{\log{2}}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\log(1-P(Y_n< K))$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log2}{n}=0$, we have to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(1-P(Y_n< K))=-\frac{k^2}{2}$, right? How do I do that?

Comment: Further rewrite $\mathbb{P}(Y_n < K) = \Phi(\sqrt{n} K)$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf and apply l'Hopital's rule twice.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! Tricky stuff!